# Merging two 301 redirects into one in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I want to redirect
www.mysite.com/* to mysite.com/*
and
/forum/* to /*

The lines I managed on .htaccess are:

```
RewriteEngine on

#www.mysite.com -> mysite.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/$1 [R=301,C]

#/forum/ to /
RedirectMatch 301 ^/forum/(.*)$ http://mysite.com/$1
```

These instructions create two 301 redirections for URLS like http://www.mysite.com/forum/

1. Does it hurt SEO? In what extent?
2. How can I merge those two
   instructions and create one single
   instruction (maybe with complex
   RegExps) that does it with a single
   301 redirection?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

301 has slight effect on external links to your old URLs. But nothing significant. 
As apparently google shaves little PR juice because of redirect.

Your all internal links need to be changed  to your new format. So that all the internal links juice is transfered as it is.

Regarding part 2, better keep them two separate rewrites, as both looks different functionality. (They wont hurt much).